# What makes this query so slow? 150,000 affected rows take more than 1.5 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been stuck on this query for more than 2 days. I already tried sub-queries (in SELECT), I already tried "join everything with LEFT JOIN and `count(column.id)` (NULL = 0)".

Campaigns Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaigns` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `campaigns`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
  
ALTER TABLE `campaigns`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Operating Systems Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `operating_systems` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `operating_systems`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `operating_systems_name_index` (`name`),
  ADD KEY `operating_systems_version_index` (`version`),
  ADD KEY `operating_systems_name_version_index` (`name`,`version`);

ALTER TABLE `operating_systems`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Clicks Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `clicks` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `campaign_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `operating_system_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cost_integral` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `clicks`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `c_c_ca` (`campaign_id`,`created_at`),
  ADD KEY `c_c_os_ca` (`campaign_id`,`operating_system_id`,`created_at`);

ALTER TABLE `clicks`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `c_c` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_id`) REFERENCES `campaigns` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `c_os` FOREIGN KEY (`operating_system_id`) REFERENCES `operating_systems` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `clicks`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Conversions Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `conversions` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `click_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `payout_integral` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `conversions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `conversions_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  ADD KEY `conversions_click_id_created_at_index` (`click_id`,`created_at`);

ALTER TABLE `conversions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `conversions_click_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`click_id`) REFERENCES `clicks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `conversions`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Slow Query:

```
select operating_systems.name,
    ifnull(sum(metrics.clicks_count), 0) as clicks_count,
    ifnull(sum(metrics.conversions_count), 0) as conversions_count,
    ifnull(round(((100 / sum(metrics.clicks_count)) * sum(metrics.conversions_count)), 2), 0) as conversion_rate,
    cast(ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0) as unsigned) as cost_integral,
    cast(ifnull((sum(metrics.cost_integral) / sum(metrics.clicks_count)), 0) as unsigned) as cpc_integral,
    cast(ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) as unsigned) as revenue_integral,
    cast(ifnull((ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) / sum(metrics.clicks_count)), 0) as unsigned) as epc_integral,
    cast((ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) - ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0)) as signed) as profit_integral,
    round((
            case 
                when (ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) = 0 and ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0) = 0)
                    then 0
                when (ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) = 0 and ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0) > 0)
                    then - 100
                when (ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) > 0 and ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0) = 0)
                    then 100
                when (ifnull(sum(metrics.revenue_integral), 0) > 0 and ifnull(sum(metrics.cost_integral), 0) > 0)
                    then ((sum(metrics.revenue_integral) / sum(metrics.cost_integral)) * 100)
                end
            ), 2) as roi
from operating_systems
left join (
    select c1.operating_system_id as operating_system_id,
        count(c1.id) as clicks_count,
        sum(c1.cost_integral) as cost_integral,
        count(c2.id) as conversions_count,
        sum(c2.payout_integral) as revenue_integral
    from clicks as c1
    left join conversions as c2 on c2.click_id = c1.id
    where c1.campaign_id = '2' and c1.created_at >= '2021-07-06 00:00:00' and c1.created_at <= '2021-07-14 23:59:59'
    group by c1.operating_system_id
    ) as metrics on operating_systems.id = metrics.operating_system_id
group by operating_systems.name;
```

Explain:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | operating_systems | NULL | index | operating_systems_name_index,operating_systems_name_version_index | operating_systems_name_index | 1022 | NULL | 12 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 8 | dn_tracker.operating_systems.id | 777 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 2 | DERIVED | c1 | NULL | ref | c_os,c_ca,c_c_v,c_c_ca,c_c_b_ca,c_c_os_ca | c_c_os_ca | 8 | const | 155472 | 50.00 | Using index condition |
| 2 | DERIVED | c2 | NULL | ref | conversions_click_id_created_at_index | conversions_click_id_created_at_index | 8 | dn_tracker.c1.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |

Profiling:

| Query_ID | Duration | Query |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.49035375 | select operating_systems.name, ifnull(sum(metrics.clicks_count), 0) as clicks_count, ifnull(sum(metrics.conversions_count), 0) as conversions_count, ifnull(round(((100 / sum(metrics.clicks_count)) * sum(metrics.conversions_count)), 2), 0) as conversion_rate, cast(ifnull(sum(metri |

What could be the reason that this query, with "only" ~150,000 rows, takes between 1.5 and 6 seconds? I think I created the right indexes etc., so I don't understand why this query takes so long on a server with 12 CPUs (Dedicated) and 16 GB RAM.

Comment: how long does just the subquery take (try `select count(*) from (select c1.operating_system_id...) as metrics`)?  how many rows does it return?  how many distinct operating_systems.id are there?  ditto for operating_systems.name?

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using? Looks like some versions don't have parallel query execution, so you're only using one of those 12 cores. It seems fairly reasonable to me for this query to take 1.5 seconds on a single core even if all of the data is already sitting in memory.

Comment: It LOOKs like your outer Select is joining a table and a subquery that are both of operating_system_id cardinality, even though some rows may be missing from the subquery.  If that is true, then you should remove the outer Group By and ALL those sum() functions in the select list.  That could save you some execution time...  still need the IfNull() functions...

Comment: @ysth The result of `select count(*) from (...) as metrics` is 13. How I come to the result of your other questions, I unfortunately do not know. 

@JohnTseng mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

@ChrisMaurer Even without all the mathematical calculations and the `group by` at the end of the query, the execution takes 1.67 seconds.

Comment: and how long does that select count take?  that will tell you whether to concentrate on the subquery or the outer query in looking for optimizations

Comment: @ysth It takes 1.39 to 2.52 seconds.

Comment: it looks like it is using the c_c_os_ca index because of the group by, but would do better to use the c_c_ca index.  try changing `from clicks as c1` to `from clicks as c1 use index (c_c_ca)`

Comment: @ysth I don't know how to mark comments as "solution", but your hint regarding the wrong index was great. The query time has been cut in half! In combination with summary tables this is very, very good! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Build and maintain a summary table.  Add the day's data to the summary table after midnight each night.  Then rewrite this "report" to work from the summary table.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

In some cases, a summary table will speed 'reports' up by 10-fold.

Also, this may help:

```
conversions: INDEX(click_id, payout_integral)
```

MySQL has essentially no parallel execution.